# How do I save NAnt log output to a file?

Tags: logging, nant

In my build script how can I set a destination for NAnt's log messages?

Idealy I'd like to just specify a file path. Then, on each build, NAnt would overwrite this file's contents with its message output.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [NANT Loggers and Listeners](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85-rc1/help/fundamentals/listeners.html#DefaultLogger) for that. One option is to pass a logfile parameter to the command. This file is overwritten on every execution.

You could have a batch file that calls NAnt for each build file and corresponding output.

```
NAnt.exe -build:[build file for PROJ1] -logfile:c:\temp\BuildOutput1.txt
NAnt.exe -build:[build file for PROJ2] -logfile:c:\temp\BuildOutput2.txt
.
.
```

I would suggest you look into at a [Continuous Integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) app, like [CruiseControl.NET](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/) if you haven't already done so.

Comment: I've seen the documentation. I'm also planning on TeamCity for my CI. I'm still not sure how to get from your suggestion to my goal. Can you explain a little more about how I can configure the default logger to write to a file instead of the console from within my build script?